# Select only new none duplicate values

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4

I have a table of Client information that I need to pull Distinct States from but only where the time stamp is newer than the last check.  The distinct values need to be distinct from all old checks also.

Table:

```
Name         City            State           created_at
Dan          Springfield     Ohio            2014-03-25 17:44:19.000000
Jon          Philadelphia    Pennsylvania    2014-03-25 17:44:19.000000
Sue          Hollywood       California      2014-03-25 17:44:19.000000
Ann          Oxford          Ohio            2014-03-25 19:44:19.000000
Al           Chicago         Illinois        2014-03-25 19:44:19.000000
```

So say I already ran checked once and found Ohio, Pennsylvania, and California.  Then two new entries were added.  The next time I run my check I need to find only Illinois and not Ohio again.

I tried this,

```
SELECT State, created_at FROM (SELECT DISTINCT State, created_at FROM clients) as temp WHERE created_at > '2014-03-25 17:44:19.000000' ORDER BY State ASC
```

After running this I realized my thought process was wrong on this one as I still get duplicates.

I think what I need is to , Find all new entries

```
Select State FROM clients WHERE created_at > '2014-03-25 17:44:19.000000'
```

then on that result,

Select State FROM result WHERE State is not in the (clients WHERE created_at < '2014-03-25 17:44:19.000000')

But I have no idea how to do this.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If something was created since the last check, then `min(created_at)` is after the last check date.  Hence, the following should do what you want:

```
select c.state
from clients c
group by state
having min(created_at) >= @yourlastcheck;
```

Comment: Yes that worked perfectly.  Thank You.
Any chance you can explain the c part? I'm not following what "c" is actually doing.

Comment: @user3462055 . . . `c` is called a "table alias".  It is an abbreviation for the table name.  In this context, it is optional, but sometimes (notably for self-joins) it might be necessary.